# Weird Behaviour: IE11 + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, tomcat

I created an AngularJS application which is served via Tomcat and I am experiencing some weird behaviour on IE11. When I serve the site from my development machine (Win7) the site works as expected on both Chrome and IE but when I deploy to the test server (linux) while it still works fine on Chrome, nothing shows up in IE11 except the following messages in the console:

[image]

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` to index.html solved the problem